# Powershell, SQL Server, SQLBULKCOPY: Syntax to specify codepage or encoding

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlbulkcopy, codepages

I'm using a Powershell script found at ((https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/powershell-high-performance-techniques-for-importing-csv-to-sql-server/) to load data from quotes delimited, comma separated .csv in to a SQL Server (2016) database.

The source csv files contain extended characters within the data such as umlauts in some first names and the m2 (only it's a little 2) for metre squared. I believe I need to need to specify a codepage of 65001 in order for such extended character values to flow from the csv file and be inserted into varchar datatypes.

I don't know the syntax to specify a particular codepage (or encoding) value?

I've attempted this:

```
$bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionstring,([System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions] 'TableLock'))
```

```
$bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = $table
$bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0
$bulkcopy.batchsize = $batchsize
#$bulkcopy.Codepage = $codepage
```

where $codepage is already assigned the value of 65001 but the above syntax errors? I've googled this for ages but not found an example. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If these characters are outside of the codepage for the database within SQL Server then using a UITF-8 codepage will achieve nothing. Should your column not be an `nvarchar`, or is your database in a UTF-8 collation?

Comment: Collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Currently the characters are being stored as question marks. I have tried a sql datatype of nvarchar but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you actually give us an [mre]? With sample data and the definition of your table?

Comment: Aside... What's the point of making things process as quickly as possible when you already know it's doing the job incorrectly? Anywhere you see a delimited file reading process use "Read Line" or "Split" operations you can throw it in the bin because you know it cannot handle delimited files where field data may contain line breaks, text qualifiers (e.g.: quotes `"`) or delimiters (e.g.: `,`). Have a read through [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) to understand delimited file formats.

Comment: `Latin1_General_CI_AS` doesn't support UTF-8 encoded characters, it is code page 1252. If you want to store character data in the database in UTF-8 format (code page 65001) then you need to use one of the `*_UTF8` collations, ref: [Collation and Unicode support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support). That requires SQL Server 2019 or later. If you're stuck on SQL Server 2016 then you'll need to use `nchar` or `nvarchar` columns which will store all of the Basic Multilingual Plane code points supported by UCS-2.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple split command to read CSV files is not recommended because the CSV format is more complex than it appears, with different delimiters, quoted fields, and line breaks within fields. To handle these complexities and correctly parse CSV files, it's important to use a dedicated CSV parsing library like CsvHelper, which supports a variety of CSV specifications, including RFC 4180.
Additionally, if the CSV file contains characters that are not in the default encoding, the output might display incorrectly. To ensure that the file is read correctly, it's important to check the encoding of the file and set the appropriate encoding before reading it.

This here is a sample using csvhelper that is acutely a nuget package inside powershell. This sample adds records to System.Data.DataTable and to a PSCustomObject. You need to implement the batch bulk inserts from DataTable on your own. (This should not be too difficult).

As in the comment mentioned there can be several pitfalls here, incompliant source files, incorrect reading of the source files. Database collations, applications that read from db incorrectly. On top you don't have real control over all parts of these environments. This should give your script side most correct phrasing throught CSVHelper and some encoding control, if your editing is limited to the PowerShell script.

To test the script below just create a C:\temp\test.csv

```
entry1,entry2
x,Üüüü¢+Это текст
a,z
```

Advantage: RFC 4180 Compliant and control over the read/write encoding to the datatable

```
function Convert-Encoding {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$text,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Text.Encoding]$sourceEncodingName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Text.Encoding]$targetEncodingName
    )
 
    $bytes = $sourceEncodingName.GetBytes($text)
    $newText = $targetEncodingName.GetString($bytes)
    return $newText
}

# Useing the CsvHelper nuget package inside powershell
Install-Module -Name GetNuGet
$nuget = Get-NuGet -Version 6.5.0
& $nuget install CsvHelper -Version 30.0.1 -OutputDirectory "$env:USERPROFILE\.nuget\packages\"
Add-Type -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\.nuget\packages\CsvHelper\30.0.1\lib\net45\CsvHelper.dll"

$sourceEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$targetEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default

$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new("C:\temp\test.csv",$sourceEncoding)
$csv = [CsvHelper.CsvReader]::new($reader, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

$records = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$csv.Read()
$csv.ReadHeader()
$datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$header = $csv.HeaderRecord

foreach($item in $header)
{
    $datatable.Columns.Add($item);
}

while ($csv.Read()) {

    $record = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Id = Convert-Encoding -text $csv.GetField("entry1") -sourceEncodingName ($sourceEncoding) -targetEncodingName ($targetEncoding) 
        Name = Convert-Encoding -text $csv.GetField("entry2") -sourceEncodingName ($sourceEncoding) -targetEncodingName ($targetEncoding)
    }

    $records.Add($record)

    $workRow = $datatable.NewRow()
    foreach($item in $header)
    {
        $workRow[$item] = Convert-Encoding -text $csv.GetField($item) -sourceEncodingName ($sourceEncoding) -targetEncodingName ($targetEncoding)
    }
    $datatable.Rows.Add($workRow)

}

$csv.Dispose()
$reader.Dispose()

Write-Output $records
```

This will endup in the datatable as

```
entry1,entry2
x,ÃœÃ¼Ã¼Ã¼Â¢+Ð­Ñ‚Ð¾ Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑÑ‚
a,z
```

Cause i changed the encoding in between.

```
$sourceEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$targetEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```